# How to get the text from multiple text fields? Net beans and Scene Builder

Tags: java, netbeans, textfield, netbeans-8, scenebuilder

I have a problem with getting text from multiple text fields.  I'm using Net Beans with Scene Builder as an UI-Extension.  Every time I run the program, I get the following error:

*Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException*

I have initialized my text fields' as follows:
**EmailController.java**

```
@FXML private TextField txtTo;
@FXML private TextField txtSubject;
@FXML private TextField txtMessage;
```

And when I press 'send' I want to print the text I got from my text fields.

> txtMessage being a multiline textfield.

**EmailController.java**

```
@FXML
private void handleSendAction(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println(txtTo.getText());
    System.out.println(txtSubject.getText());
    System.out.print(txtMessage.getText());
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Caused by:**

> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
>       at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
>       ... 48 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at clientv2.pkg0.EmailController.handleSendAction(EmailController.java:46)
>       ... 58 more

**Email.fxml**

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="375.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: #d3d3e8;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="clientv2.pkg0.EmailController">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="txtTo" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="36.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="590.0" promptText="TO:" />
      <TextField fx:id="txtSubject" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="66.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="590.0" promptText="SUBJECT:" />
      <TextArea fx:id="txtMessage" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="96.0" prefHeight="240.0" prefWidth="590.0" promptText="Enter Text Here..." />
      <Button fx:id="btnSend" layoutX="477.0" layoutY="342.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleSendAction" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="118.0" style="-fx-background-color: #bcb1cc;" text="Send" />
      <Label layoutX="273.0" layoutY="2.0" text="Email">
         <font>
            <Font size="23.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Also the event handler is in my Email.fmxl and the id of each text field corresponds to the text field names I have initialized.

Comment: Show full exception message.

Comment: @mrmcwolf the error message is exceptionally long error message

Comment: @JenniferBester - even so - the part you have provided has no helpful information. Presumably, there is a "caused by" further down the trace. You should at least post the last "caused by" part, showing the original exception.

Comment: yes, it is long, but the important part is towards the end. what you have said does not say anything.

Comment: @ mrmcwolf, I have edited my question to display the caused by section

Comment: the object in `EmailController.java` on line 46 is not initialized.

Comment: Can you give us the content of your fxml file?

Comment: @aaronstein I have added the fxml file in my question

Comment: Which line is 46 ?  (mark it with a comment in the code). [MCVE] would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`TextField` and `TextArea` are two different controls. In the FXML file she declared that `TextArea` but in the controller annotated `TextField`.

For the code to go mad

```
@FXML private TextField txtMessage;
```

With

```
@FXML private TextArea txtMessage;
```

Comment: Yes he's right thats why you got a NullPointerException